# Adding header part and closing tags to XHTML content

Tags: linux, xml, bash, xhtml

I have a  multiple XHTML pages without header part and closing HTML tags (file002.xhtml, file015.xhtml,etc). How I can add the header part and closing tags to all these pages, use some scripting, or macro? (Linux Debian). I need to add these parts before and after content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xml:lang="en-us" lang="en-us" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops" xmlns:ns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis">
<head>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="1260143570.css"/>
</head>
<body>

= CONTENT =

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use an XSLT-1.0 processor like `xsltproc`(Linux), or any other.
A suitable XSLT-stylesheet could look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ws="http://ws">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html xml:lang="en-us" lang="en-us" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops" xmlns:ns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis">
            <head>
                <title></title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="1260143570.css"/>
            </head>
            <body>
                <!-- CONTENT -->
                <xsl:copy-of select="document('input.xml')" />   <!-- Place the input filename here! -->
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This works for 1 file.
Pay attention to the fact that you have to call this stylesheet with a bogus XML file as a parameter.

---

For many more files, you can create a loop with XSLT-2.0's `result-docment` function. So create an XML file with the files that should be included in your output, like this (`a.xml`, `b.xml`, `c.xml`):

```
<root>
    <file>a.xml</file>
    <file>b.xml</file>
    <file>c.xml</file>
</root>
```

Then, an XSLT-2.0

```
 stylesheet to handle this could look like this:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ws="http://ws">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="/root/file">
            <xsl:result-document href="{substring-before(.,'.')}-WithHeader.html" method="xhtml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes">
                <html xml:lang="en-us" lang="en-us" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops" xmlns:ns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis">
                    <head>
                        <title></title>
                        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="1260143570.css"/>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        <!-- CONTENT -->
                        <xsl:copy-of select="document(.)" />
                    </body>
                </html>
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This stylesheet creates one new XML file for each input XML file specified in the XML passed as parameter and appends the string `-WithHeader` to the filename in `/root/file`. This approach probably comes closest to your requirement; just create the XML file with the filenames and run the stylesheet. That should be all.

Comment: But all pages have _.XHTML_ extension, and in the output I also need _.XHTML_ files.

Comment: Well, then just change the file extensions in the code above :-) The relevant part is the `method="xhtml"` attribute on the `xsl:result-document` (or stylesheet in the first one) which sets the file format.

Comment: What is proper syntax for command? I run command `./gestalt  test.xsl list.xml` Got error: `Warning: XSLT 1.0 stylesheet is being run on an XSLT 2.0 processor.
At line 7 in file:///home/deffo/Downloads/Recipe/GESTALT/test.xsl:
Fatal error: http://www.gobosoft.com/eiffel/gobo/gexslt/extension#OUTPUT_RESOLVER_ERROR: Invalid stdout: URI`

Comment: I edited the answer to remove the warning (Changed version number in the second stylesheet). But the error is more complicated: I guess you are not constructing a valid URI in the `href` attribute of the `xsl:result-docment`. I can't help you with that, because it heavily depends on your environment. Maybe you need to use a file path and not a URI...really don't know. Sorry.

Comment: How can I use file path in the `href` attribute  of `<xsl:result-document`?

Comment: At first, try to use relative path's instead of absolute - like the ones I used in the above example code. And always make sure that the target paths do have write permissions. Absolute paths may also be blocked by your browser's security settings, but this is really a question of its own.

Comment: I put test.xsl and list.xml files in directory where is .xhtml files and run processor command `./gestalt test.xsl  list.xml`: no files was created, no any errors shown. Tried also to rename .xhtml pages to .xml pages, but no difference, just no files created. Target folder have write permissions (chmod 777).

Comment: Ok, another idea: Can you add your test.xml and list.xml to your question with an edit (Link below the question), so I can have a look at it?

Comment: your code is fine. The problem was in buggy Gestalt XSLT processor, I found two bugs, that produce errors.

Comment: Glad that you found the error :-)